# DOM is receiving empty strings

Tags: javascript, dom

so i have been trying make a calculator webpage just to get used to DOM, but for some reason when i try to get user input i receive empty strings.

this is my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator DOM Practice</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Calculator Web page</h1>
        <!-- <form> -->
           <div class="prompts">Please enter your first number</div>
           <input id="first_num" type="text" placeholder="first num"><br>
           <div class = "prompts">Please enter second number</div>
           <input id="second_num" type = "text" placeholder="second num"><br>

           <label for="operator">Chose your operation: </label>
           <select id="operator" name = "operator">
               <option value ="minus">-</option>
               <option value ="addition">+</option>
               <option value ="multiply">*</option>
               <option value ="divide">/</option>
           </select>
           
           <button id="calc_button" type="submit">Calculate</button>
        <!-- </form> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript where i receive the user input:

```
var first = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
var second = document.getElementById("second_num").value;
// var oper = document.getElementById("operator").value;   //this only give sme 
first index
var oper = operator.options[operator.selectedIndex].value;
var button = document.getElementById("calc_button");
first = Number(first);
second = Number(second);
```

I have tried using `document.getElementId("first_num").text` but for some reason it as if my script runs as soon as the webpage is started, so it sets those variables when they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

As you said this script is looking for the empty input value when the page is first rendered. You need to add an event lister which calls a function when the input value is updated.

```
var firstInput = document.getElementById("first_num");      
var firstNumber;

function updateFirstNumber(e) {
     firstNumber = e.target.value;
}

first.addEventListener('change', updateFirstNumber);
```

[More information on events (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)